# Как сделать, чтобы каждый потоковый объект информировал другие?

Tags: потоки-данных, java, c++, c#

Всем доброго времени суток! Объект потока создается динамически. Как сделать, чтобы каждый потоковый объект информировал другие? (Объекты в дальнейшем "прорисовываются" шариками. Шариков может быть неограниченное количество. Необходимо сравнивать координаты каждого шарика с остальными.) Языки: C#, C++, Java.
В книгах нигде не нашел. Буду очень благодарен за ответ!

Comment: Сформулируйте задачу точнее.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все потоки работают в одном адресном пространстве. Соответственно, в методе, который выполняется в созданном потоке, должен быть доступен объект, который создан в основном потоке. Через него можно реализовать информирование. Но при этом необходимо корректно организовать синхронизацию.

Comment: Скорее всего это можно сделать простой событийной связью.
Очень хотелось бы увидеть примеры подобного кода.

Answer (score 0):

Пример кода будет выглядеть как-то так (C#).

```
var th = new Thread(item.Run);
item.Changed += (sender, e) => { /* do something */ };
th.Start();

// Метод Run объекта item
//...
if (this.Changed != null) 
  this.Changed(this, EventArgs.Empty);
```

Answer (score 0):

вам поможет реализация одного из следующих шаблонов:
[Observer](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Наблюдатель_(шаблон_проектирования)),
[Mediator](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Посредник_(шаблон_проектирования)), с примерами. советую также посмотреть английские версии.